# Recursion In a General Tree

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-structures, recursion, tree

I've created a general tree based on a Node class that has 2 pointers: next points to the node's first son , bros points to the next brother of the node.
Each node has a capacity (int) and each leaf is considered one unit of demand , the goal is to say weather or not the tree supports the demand (meaning each branch of the tree has enough capacity to supply all of the demand).

The tree building part works quite nicely but it seems there's a bug i'm missing in my supplier and recursion function. general explanation:
isSupplier(node) - checks that the node has enough capacity to support all leafs under its branch.
canDemandBeAnswered(node) - recursive function that is supposed to call isSupplier for all nodes starting with the leafs going upward.

problem is that after the recursion encounters the first leaf it gets stuck on an unknown node (at height 1 with zero sons which is impossible because if the node is a leaf the recursion isn't called!)

Hopefully someone can find something i missed , thank you!

```
        // This method checks if this node can supply all of its leafs.

    bool isSupplier()
    {
        if ( this->isLeaf() ) { return 1;}
        else 
        {
            this->num_of_leafs = this->Count_Leafs();
            Node* iter = this->next;
            while ( (iter != NULL) )
            {
                if ( iter->isLeaf() == 0 ) 
                { this->num_of_leafs += iter->num_of_leafs; }
                iter = iter->bros;
            }
        }
        if (this->capacity < this->num_of_leafs) { return 0; }
        else { return 1; }
    }

     bool canDemandBeAnswered(Node* root)
    {
        cout << "Height: " << root->getHeight() << " , sons: " << root->Count_Sons() << " ,bros: " << root->getNumBros() << " ,leafs: " << root->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
        if ( root->isLeaf() ) { return 1; }
        Node* iter = root->next;
        while ( iter != NULL )
        {
            canDemandBeAnswered(iter);
            iter->getNextBro();
        }
        return root->isSupplier();
    };
```

The tree creation and recursive call:

```
    Node* s8 = new Node(8);
Node* s5 = new Node(5);
Node* s6 = new Node(6);
for(int i=0; i < 2 ; i++){
    s6->addChild(new Node());      
}

Node* s7 = new Node(7);
Node* s2 = new Node(2);
for(int i=0; i < 3 ; i++){
    s2->addChild(new Node());
}

Node* s3 = new Node(3);
Node* s2_2 = new Node(2);  
s2_2->addChild(new Node());

Node* s4 = new Node(4);
 for(int i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
    s4->addChild(new Node());
}

Node* s1 = new Node(1);
 for(int i=0; i < 2 ; i++){
    s1->addChild(new Node());      
}
Node* s2_3 = new Node(2);
 for(int i=0; i < 4 ; i++){
    s2_3->addChild(new Node());
}
Node* s2_4 = new Node(2);  
for(int i=0; i < 3 ; i++){
    s2_4->addChild(new Node());
}
s8->addChild(s5);
s8->addChild(s6);    
s5->addChild(s7);
s5->addChild(s2);
s6->addChild(s3);
s6->addChild(s2_2);
s7->addChild(s4);
s7->addChild(s1);
s3->addChild(s2_3);
s3->addChild(s2_4);
cout << "s8 height: " << s8->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s8->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s8->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s8->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s5 height: " << s5->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s5->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s5->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s5->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s6 height: " << s6->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s6->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s6->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s6->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s7 height: " << s7->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s7->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s7->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s7->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s2 height: " << s2->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s2->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s2->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s2->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s3 height: " << s3->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s3->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s3->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s3->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s2_2 height: " << s2_2->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s2_2->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s2_2->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s2_2->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s4 height: " << s4->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s4->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s4->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s4->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s1 height: " << s1->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s1->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s1->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s1->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s2_3 height: " << s2_3->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s2_3->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s2_3->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s2_3->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
cout << "s2_4 height: " << s2_4->getHeight() << " , sons: " << s2_4->Count_Sons() << " , bros: " << s2_4->getNumBros() << " , num of leaf: " << s2_4->getNumLeafs() << " \n";
bool ans = hw4->canDemandBeAnswered(s8);
```

and the big finale , my debug output:
[image]

Comment: Asking others to debug your code for you is not constructive ;).  You should instead use a debugger (or add print statements) to track the progress of your code, and compare that with what you expected.  Once you've isolated the problem, then you can create a minimal test-case.

Comment: Also, please paste the actual text of your console output, not an image of the output!

Comment: Hi Oli , i added the print comments and also added an image of the output and where exactly in the recursion processes the bug happens.
it's not that i can't find it , i just can't explain it.

Comment: If you know where in the code the problem lies, then you can inspect the values of variables, etc. at that point.  You can then work backward to figure out *why* that occurred.

Comment: How can i see variable values in the debugger? specifically , is there a way to see where a pointer is pointing towards?
thanks by the way :-)

Comment: I'm not massively familiar with the Visual C++ debugger, but if you run with F5, rather than Ctrl+F5, you run under the debugger.  You can then set breakpoints (or wait for the program to crash).  You will then be able to inspect variable (probably by hovering over them in the source code), and it should be possible to follow pointers through the GUI.

Comment: Yes, in VS you can just look at the locals and put in the appropriate break points for where you want to look.

Comment: i'm using breakpoints and F11 frequently , just not very good with pointer values i guess. thanks :-)

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Variables can be inspected by Watch (1&2), Locals, Autos and Inspect windows. You can't easily check, *what* the pointer points to, but you can check, *if* pointer points to object it is supposed to (note down addresses of instances after their construction). I can only guess, that there's some kind of broken link or not initialized field problem.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 , if you can explain me how to follow pointers or direct me to a tutorial i'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Q and write "Locals", then select option, which shows the "locals" window. You'll be presented with a list of local variables and their values. All objects will be presented by memory address. Write them down. Then you will be able to track down, which path the algorithm chooses and which link is broken (eg. if next and bros fields point to correct nodes).

Comment: Thanks Spook , my problem was rather silly but i did learn to read variable locations so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop

```
while (iter != NULL)
{
    canDemandBeAnswered(iter);
    iter->getNextBro();
}
```

doesn't do anything since you never modify `iter`.

I suspect you meant to say

```
iter = iter->getNextBro();
```

You're also ignoring the return value of the recursive call, which is probably not what you intended, but it's not entirely clear what it's supposed to do.

Comment: thank you so much molbdnilo! can't believe i missed the iterator thing.
any idea how can i use the return value of the recursive call?
the idea is that if all recursive call return 1 then the function returns 1 and if one or more returns 0 the function returns 0.